# What is the best way to backup Brackets plugins?

Tags: brackets, adobe-brackets

I know the plugins are installed in

Mac: ~/Library/Application Support/Brackets/extensions/user
Win: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Brackets\extensions\user
Linux: ~/.config/brackets/extensions/user

Otherwise, I can view the location from the menu "Help > Show Extensions Folder".

Is there any better solution than to zip and move it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Install "Extensions Bulk Installer"
- Open up Extensions Bulk Install Shortcut – Ctrl(Cmd)+Alt+M on your version of Brackets, which you want to export.
- Click on Export to File
- Switch Computers and Import